# Reloading page in the middle of a transaction

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

If a user stops a page from loading completely in the middle of a transaction and then refreshes the page, will transaction apply twice?

Comment: Not totally sure but I imagine it'll depend on whether it hits the `COMMIT` command or not before the refresh occurs.

Comment: The transaction is happening on the server and is easily tested. A refresh on the client-side would send a new, even if duplicate, request.

Comment: Once the user has sent the request, it is sent. There's not usually a way of knowing if the user clicks "stop" in their browser. Many people would use unique values in the post form to stop it happening twice, or the Post/Redirect/Get workflow to stop page refreshes being a big issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is - you have to check. Transactions fail if even one query doesn't execute correctly. However, here's the real issue - if the user aborts the loading, that doesn't mean the server will stop executing the code. Aborting the page load just means that the user decided not to receive the data back. Your web server doesn't have to comply, nor does PHP - they might not even be aware of the fact that user closed the pipe on their end. Now we enter a whole different play area - PHP can be embedded into servers or it can act as a standalone server (known as `php-fpm`). If PHP is embedded into a server such as Apache via mod_php - Apache decides whether it will interrupt the thread or process that's executing the PHP process. It can still decide to execute the whole thing, collect the result and then it will try to write the result back to the socket - only to realize that the user isn't there any more.

As you can see, the complexity of your problem is not as simple as "what if user aborts" - it's not up to the user to control program execution *on your web server*.

Now, let's assume that the web server is willing to play ball and that it will somehow tell PHP to abort execution - in that case, transaction won't  execute, it will fail because commit won't be issued.

If the server isn't willing to play ball or it simply hasn't got the means to abort the PHP process - then yes, you will end up with two transactions executed, or more, depending what your users do.